# QSpatiaLite: Cannot create table

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, spatialite

I am running QGIS 1.8 (SpatiaLite 3.0.1) and QSpatiaLite 6.0.1.

I have a spatial table `EventPrecise` (with geometry column `p` in EPSG:4326). I want to join this table with another, non-spatial table `Event` and produce a new spatial table out of it with EPSG:21781, while at the same time filtering on a non-spatial attribute `t`. This is my query:

```
SELECT e.id, e.oid, e.type, e.subtype, e.t, ST_Transform(ep.p, 21781) AS p
FROM event e LEFT OUTER JOIN eventprecise ep ON e.id = ep.eid
WHERE datetime(e.t) > datetime('2013-02-05 18:20:00') AND datetime(e.t) < datetime('2013-02-19 08:31:00');
```

When running this query in QSpatiaLite with options "Create Spatial Table & Load in QGIS", and geometry column = "p", I get the error:

```
'%s' doesn't correspond to a geometry field, try with another field name
```

Creating a View works though.. is this a bug?

**EDIT**: Turns out that it works when doing an `INNER JOIN`, so `p` is never null - still, is this normal behaviour?